# Powershell append to file not appending string

Tags: powershell

I defined a function to append a title to an output file.

```
function appendTitle($filePath, [string]$title){

Add-Content -Path $filePath -Value "+------------------------+" 
Add-Content -Path $filePath -Value $title 
Add-Content -Path $filePath -Value "+------------------------+" 


}
```

The issue is that if I run it as such:

```
appendTitle($filePath, "Net Accounts")
```

But in the output file it doesn't include the $title variable but just displays:

```
+------------------------+

+------------------------+
```

So where did my variable go that I wanted to append?

Answer (score 3):

It's Because you run it inside a parentheses, run it like that:

```
appendTitle $filepath "Net Accounts"
```

Comment: More info: What the function is expecting is 2 arguments, a `$filepath` argument, which isn't typed so it could be anything, and a `$title` argument which it expects to be a string. What you pass is 1 argument, which is an array of two thing, first is `$filepath`, and second is "Net Accounts", and no second argument at all.